# Are $z^n$ and $p(z)/|p(z)|$ homotopic?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $p:\mathbb C\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ be a complex polynomial with no zeros and degree $n$. Is it true that the maps $f, g:S^1\longrightarrow S^1$ given by $$f(z)=z^n\quad \textrm{and}\quad g(x)=\frac{p(z)}{|p(z)|}$$ are homotopic?

**Obs:** I'm supposing $p$ has no zeros for finding a contradiction for a proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: A complex polynomial with no zeros of degree $n$?? Please give us an example of such a thing.

Comment: If $n \ge 1$, finding a complex polynomial with no zeros is mission impossible!

Comment: @Commenters This is part of a proof of the fundamental theorem. He's assuming $p$ has no roots for the sake of contradiction.

Comment: But if all the roots of $p$ are in the unit disk …

Comment: @MikeMiller you're right =)

Comment: It's hard to talk about objects that don't exist, but it's not quite true, you have to enlarge your circle a bit. See any algebraic topology book. Basically, try to write down a homotopy and then think about what goes wrong.